# How to add or subtract from date with format DDMMYYYY in bash?

Tags: shell, date, unix, command-line

This is working

```
date -d '2019-12-13 -5 day' +%d%m%Y
```

However, the following is throwing an error to me

```
date -d "13122019  -5 day" +%d%m%Y
```

Comment: The problem is not `+%d%m%Y` but `13122019  -5 day`.

Comment: What are you suggesting, tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @bobdylan not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man date`

> The  --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even  "next  Thursday". [...]  The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.

**tl;dr:** Seems like you cannot specify the format of the input. Use one of the known formats, for instance

```
date -d '2019-12-13 -5 day' +%d%m%Y
```

To automatically convert a date from `DDMMYYYY` format to `YYYY-MM-DD` you can use `sed` ...

```
date -d "$(sed -E 's/(..)(..)(.*)/\3-\2-\1/' <<< 13122019) -5 day" +%d%m%Y
```

... or bash ...

```
d=13122019
date -d "${d:4}-${d:2:2}-${d:0:2} -5 day" +%d%m%Y
```

Comment: The problem is input and the output of my script date is in %d%m%Y. So eventually to solve the issue I need to convert a date in some other format.

Comment: @arunpal I added what you need.